# From a one-hot representation to the labels

Tags: python, numpy, tensor, threshold

My predictions are under a tensor `pred`, and `pred.shape` is `(4254, 10, 3)`. So we have `4254`  matrices of dimension `(10, 3)`. Let's take a look on one of those matrices.

```
W = array([[0.04592975, 0.09632163, 0.85774857],
          [0.03408821, 0.27141285, 0.6944989 ],
          [0.02538731, 0.4691383 , 0.50547445],
          [0.01959289, 0.6456455 , 0.33476162],
          [0.01333424, 0.7494791 , 0.23718661],
          [0.0109237 , 0.77042925, 0.218647  ],
          [0.01438793, 0.7796771 , 0.20593494],
          [0.01474626, 0.6817438 , 0.30350992],
          [0.02189695, 0.57687664, 0.40122634],
          [0.03810155, 0.5130332 , 0.44886518]], dtype=float32)
```

As you can see by the above example, there's 10 vectors which represents a one-hot representation of a label. For instance, `np.argmax([0.04592975, 0.09632163, 0.85774857]) = 2`.

Why do I proceed by batch of 10 vectors? I am working on a time series forecasting problem where at time `t_0`, I predict the next 10 labels for time `t_1` to time `t_10`.

For each of those matrices, I would be interested to get back the original labels. So for the matrix `W`, I should get the array  `array([2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])`.

Let's define the threshold array `threshold_array = np.array([0.6, 0.65, 0.70, 0.75, 0.80, 0.80, 0.80, 0.80, 0.80, 0.80])` and take back `labels = array([2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])`. Assume that the neutral position is `1` and the action are `0` or `2`. The objective here is to modify `labels` according to the `threshold_array` and our matrix `W`.

If I take `W[0]`, we know that `np.argmax(W[0]) = 2` and `W[0][2] = 0.85774857`. As `W[0][2] >= threshold_array[0]`, then `labels[0]` will remain `2`.

That other example is a bit different. If I take `W[2]`, we know that `np.argmax(W[2]) = 2` and `W[2][2] = 0.50547445`. As `W[2][2] < threshold_array[2]`, then `labels[2]` will be changed from `2` to `0`.

If I apply that strategy to every vectors from `W`, `labels` is now set to `array([2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])`. Note that only an action can becomes a neutral position and not the inverse.

How can code in python that strategy to every matrices `W` inside `pred` to get a label matrix of dimension `(4254, 10)`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it is the optimal way to deal with that, but here's an answer.

```
import numpy as np

threshold_array = np.array([0.6, 0.65, 0.70, 0.75, 0.80, 0.80, 0.80, 0.80, 0.80, 0.80])   

def get_labels(W, threshold_array):

    labels = []
    for i, vect in enumerate(W):
        neutral_position = 1
        label = np.argmax(vect)
        if label in [0, 2]:
            if vect[label] < threshold_array[i]:
                labels.append(neutral_position)
            else:
                labels.append(label)
        else:
            labels.append(label)
    return np.array(labels)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    labels = []
    for matrix in pred:
        labels.append(get_labels(matrix, theshold_array))
    labels = np.array(labels)
```